# how to import java project into eclipse to run on tomcat server

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, tomcat, import

Please Provide steps to import project from outside to run on tomcat server means to get the output in browser, I have an on-line banking project using JSP,AJAX,JavaScript.

Comment: Use the import option in Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

1. On Eclipse Click File->Import , then Select General->Existing Projects into Wrokspace.
2. Select the folder which have your Project
3. Click on Finish
4. From Window->Preferences Menu, select Server->Runtime environments
5. ADd your Tomcat instance
6. From Window->Showview menu, select 'Servers'
7. On Servers Tab right click, select Add Server
8. Add Tomcat
9. Tomcat instance show up in 'Servers' Tab
10. Right click on 'Tomcat server' and select 'Add/Remove'
11. Add your Project to Tomcat
12. Right click on 'Tomcat server' again and click on 'Clean' then 'Publish'
13. Select Tomcat and click on Run button

Comment: Thanks for your information but in 10th step .If i click on add/remove  then it is showing like "there are no resources that can be added or removed from the server". Please suggest me sir.

Comment: Ok, please make sure your project is 'Web Project'. See under 'Project Explorer' there is 'Deployed Resources', under that WEB-INF, web.xml. Then select Project, and from Project menu click on Build project. Once you build, you should be able to the Module under 'Servers' -> Add/Remove

Answer (score 0):

1. In you **Project Explorer** right click 
   then Select **Import Project**

[image]

2. In the import dialog box, Select **Web** and then select **WAR file**. Click on Next.

[image]

3. Finally in the **Target Runtime** select Tomcat Apache [**Note:** Apache Tomcat must be added in your server in Eclipse]. Select the WAR file that you want to add. Click on **Finish**

[image]